# Merge 2d coordinate array into 1d character list in R

Tags: r, arrays, 2d

I have a large array with `118420` elements. The array is numeric, and the dimensions are below

```
dim(Watershed_Coords)
[1]     1 59210     2
```

The problem is that the values in this array are coordinates where `[lat]` and `[lon]` have been split. I would like to merge these to have a single character list in the form of `"[lon,lat]"` where the `,` is also included.

Comment: `paste0('[', arr[1,,1], ',', arr[1,,2], ']')` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```r
lat_lon <- paste0("[", Watershed_Coords[,,1], ", ", Watershed_Coords[,,2], "]")
```

And to demonstrate this is the correct, format, we can do:

```r
head(data.frame(lat_lon))
#>        lat_lon
#> 1 [0.74, 0.21]
#> 2 [0.93, 0.34]
#> 3 [0.58, 0.54]
#> 4  [0.8, 0.57]
#> 5 [0.39, 0.94]
#> 6 [0.64, 0.06]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
Watershed_Coords <- round(runif(59210 * 2), 2)
dim(Watershed_Coords) <- c(1, 59210, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: is there also a way to add a `,` in between each row? As an example I want to copy some of the coordinates to create a shape file, but rather than inserting `,`  is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Heres an exampel of what I meant `{coordinates: [ 
"[35.752047, -102.535045]" , "[35.752045, -102.535045]"

Comment: You can try adding `collapse = "\", \""` at the end of the `paste` call.